# Ajax Upload file on Weblogic

Tags: java, ajax, spring, weblogic

I have a problem during web service call (ajax). I put an excel file in parameter but the controller can't get it (null).
I checked data before the call and it's ok :
[image]

Here the controller :
[image]

And here the log from Weblogic server :
[image]

**There is no problem when I try with Tomcat server included in Spring Boot.**
This problem comes after deployment on Weblogic.

Do you have an idea ?

Many thanks !

Comment: As far as i know... dataType should not be text but multipart/encoded; maybe here you can find something usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: I followed this [link](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-upload-file-ajax-jquery-formdata/) and it works with tomcat. I tried to delete the datatype in the ajax query but it doesn't work when I deployed on Weblogic.